# Definir la función ultimaCifra tal que (ultimaCifra x) es la última cifra del número x

Tags: haskell

Estoy haciendo esto en haskell mediante el editor sublime pero cuando pongo en haskell:

```hs
ultimaCifra :: Int -> Int -> Int
ultimaCifra x = rem x 10
```

...me pone el siguiente error:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Int -> Int’ with actual type ‘Int’
• Possible cause: ‘rem’ is applied to too many arguments
      In the expression: rem x 10
      In an equation for ‘ultimaCifra’: ultimaCifra x = rem x 10
   |
17 | ultimaCifra x = rem x 10
   |                 ^^^^^^^^
```

¿Álguien sabe qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

En la signatura de la función `ultimaCifra` pones que recibe 2 argumentos, pero la estás definiendo con sólo un argumento. Esto implica que `ultimaCifra` recibe un argumento `Int` y devuelve una función `Int -> Int`. Sin embargo, `rem x 10` es de tipo `Int`, no `Int -> Int`.

```hs
ultimaCifra :: Int -> (Int -> Int)
utlimaCifra x = ...
```

En el error te dice que igual estás usando demasiados argumentos en `rem` ya que `rem x 10` es de tipo `Int`.

En realidad lo que pasa es que tienes mal la signatura:

```hs
ultimaCifra :: Int -> Int
ultimaCifra x = rem x 10
```